# 10 month old unlocking iPhone

Tags: iphone

My 10 month old has figured out how to open both my wife’s iPhone 7plus and my iPhone 7.  The iPhone can be locked which would require fingerprint touch or 6 digit passcode, but for example a moment ago she was ‘editing’ my carrier settings. My baby bought an app a month ago and upon my requesting a refund Apple told me to make sure my phone was locked, which i thought it had been...but gave it the benefit of the doubt.  But, recently I have been catching more and more times when we let her explore the item ensuring it’s locked only to have her unlock it.

Any ideas how she could do this? Do I need to eliminate lock screen shortcuts?  They require Touch ID.  Turn off fingerprint recognition?  I thought fingerprints were unique, and her fingers are tiny.
  I want her to be able to explore technology; so I don’t t want to completely remove all devices.

Comment: If your ten-month-old can get into a locked iPhone without having the passcode, I suggest you hire her out as a consultant to the FBI.

Comment: @MikeScott I thought about mentioning that in the post, because it is funny, but I really need a solution, so I thought I should keep it serious.

Comment: Question: how do you let her ‘explore’ the phone if it is locked?

Comment: The goal is to let her move around the lock screen, access camera, ‘look’ at red and green stocks, play/pause music if it’s streaming.  All the things one can do without actually unlocking the device.

Comment: There's something like a 1:50k chance of someone having a fingerprint that can unlock your phone. Those odds drop dramatically for a relative. I'd say you just have to keep watching her until she does it. Chances are very much against her guessing the passcode - more chance she'd lock you out.

Comment: That must be it, was not aware of that. My wife and I have our prints programmed in each others phones for data drops and whatnot. I turned off Touch ID, now I’ll observe.

Comment: @Tetsujin if you have a second could you repost this answer as it’s own answer so I can solution vote it, it’s under a comment thread right now.

Comment: Sure, I'll give it a go - though it's really only speculation, I did find the Apple KB outlining the odds, but not the reduction for a relative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's something like a 1:50k chance of someone having a fingerprint that can unlock your phone, [according to Apple](https://support.apple.com/HT204587).

Those odds drop dramatically for a relative - though right now I cannot find a citation for that, I did read it on *teh interwebz* so it must be true ;-)
Googling finds a million scare stories but I can find no hard fact to support my claim.

I'd say you just have to keep watching her until she does it, see if her fingerprint can actually unlock your phone. [I'm not experienced enough at parenting to suggest you make her do it repeatedly to see if it works.]

The chances are very much against her guessing the passcode - it would be far more likely that she'd activate the timed lockout instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that your 10mo hasn't been unlocking the phone, you're probably just leaving it available to her when it hasn't completely locked. By this, I mean you either gave it to her in an application and she figured out how to get out of it or your "require password after n minutes" setting isn't short enough. So two things I can suggest: changing the timeout and locking the environment.

**Changing the Timeout** is done from the settings menu, "Touch ID and Passcode". In there you will find a setting "Require passcode" which can be set to "immediately".

**Locking the environment** is that if you want her to play with a particular application, you could lock it down so that she can't get out of it. This is a setting called "Guided Access" which is accessed by first being on the application you want to limit her to, pressing the home button 3 times, touching "Start" in the top-right corner and then entering your passcode. This will make it that she cannot get out of the application and do anything else.

To get out of Guided Access, press the home button 3 times again, enter your passcode and click "End".

Note that there are some options you can do as well in that "Start" screen of Guided Access which can enable/disable volume buttons, touch, motion, etc. Take a look, it is relatively self-explanatory.

I heavily used Guided Access with my children when I couldn't observe what they were doing. I'd highly recommend using it with a 10mo child!

Comment: Unless this has changed in recent iOS versions, once you have a TouchID set & enabled, there is no grace period at all. Once you 'switch it off' it's locked.

Comment: I do have it set to immediately lock, and habitually lock when I put it down or give it to her. The guided access and locked environment info is great though, thanks.